# jQuery .each()

Tags: jquery, javascript

Обхожу элементы таким образом:

```
jQuery.each($('#content_wrap > .an_post'), function() {
     setTimeout(function(){console.log('Hello timeout');}, 10000);
});
```

Например

```
$('#content_wrap > .an_post').size()
```

равен 4. Тогда по идее .each обойдет 4 элемента за 40 секунд, однако срабатывает через 10 и выводит в консоль сразу 4 'Hello timeout'. Почему так происходит? Это повергает меня в пучину отчаяния!

А вообще сделать хотел что-то вроде этого:

```
jQuery.each($('#content_wrap > .an_post'), function() {
     $(this).fadeIn(1500);
});
```

Т.е. чтобы 4 элемента друг за другом исчезли с разницей в анимации где-то секунду.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/259Qd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> по идее .each обойдет 4 элемента за 40 секунд, однако срабатывает через 10 и выводит в консоль сразу 4 'Hello timeout'. Почему так происходит?

как вы знаете `setTimeout` вызывает функцию переданную в качестве параметра **через** определённый промежуток времени с момента вызова самого `setTimeout`, а т.к. в цикле 4 элемента перебираются оооочень быстро, то разница между вызовами равна милисекундам, которые на общую картину не влияют

> чтобы 4 элемента друг за другом исчезли с разницей в анимации где-то секунду

```
$('#content_wrap > .an_post').each(function(idx){
    $(this).delay(1000*idx).fadeOut(1500);
});
```

- [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)
- [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 2):

Написал на коленке. Смысл, думаю поймете)

```
jQuery.each($('#content_wrap > .an_post'), function(id) {
     $(this).delay(1000*id).fadeOut(1500);
});
```